# ObjectCache does not work for multiple solution project?

Tags: c#, caching

I have two solutions:

- in `Soultion1` I have `Console1.csproj`
- in `Solution2` I have `Console2.csproj`

In `Solution1` project `Console1.csproj` I have added value into cache
and want to get those values using  `Solution2` I have
 `Console2.csproj` but in `Console2.csproj` I'm getting null

In `Console1.csproj`

```
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(10.0);
cache.Set("mykey", "myvalue", policy);
```

In `Console2.csproj` I tried to get value from cache i get null , why so local cache does not persist ?

```
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
object mykey = cache.Get("mykey", null);
```

Comment: What makes you think the memory cache, unlike all other variables and class instances, would be available in another program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You get `null` because the item is not found](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.get(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Object
>
> A reference to the cache entry that is identified by key, if the entry exists; otherwise, null.

`MemoryCache` class works ***per process*** which mean ***2 different applications will have different cache instances***.

In order to send the data between `Console1` and `Console2` you will need them to communicate using [`Interprocess Communication`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx)/[`Sockets`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket)/etc...

You might also want to inherit from [`ObjectCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache(v=vs.110).aspx) and implement the communication layer yourself.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot access the cache from another instance of the application. to do this, you need to use something like appfabric or redis caching. right now you are running the cache which is "local" and accessible only to Console1, Console2 CANNOT access it. it is not a distributed caching system.

MemoryCache is only available to the application that hosts it.

I would suggest you use AppFabric or Redis caching or NCache. These are the most common ones used to allow multiple sources to access the global cache.